# i am trying to implement binary search treee in python , insert method not working as expected , right node element are not inserted in tree?

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree, python-3.6

```
enter code here

class Node:
    def __init__(self,data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = None
        self.right = None


class binary_tree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None


    def insert(self,data):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = Node(data)
        else:
            cur_node = self.root
            while cur_node !=None :
                if data < cur_node.data:
                    if cur_node.left is None:
                        cur_node.left = Node(data)
                        print(cur_node.left.data)
                    else:
                        cur_node = cur_node.left
                elif data > cur_node.data:
                    if cur_node.right is None:
                        cur_node.right = Node(data)
                        print(cur_node.right.data)
                    else:
                        cur_node = cur_node.right
                else:
                    print("value already exist")


binary = binary_tree()
b = binary.insert(5)
e = binary.insert(4)
h = binary.insert(7)
print(h)
```

Q. binary search tree implementation , insert method does not working as expected , inserting node to right side getting error ?
how to make this code bug free ?
binary search tree implementation .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is that it gets stuck in the `while` loop. **Note** that condition `cur_node != None` will **never** be true. This can be easily deduced from the following:

- The initial condition (before while loop is executed at least once) is always `true`, because we get to this branch only if `self.root` is not `None`.
- In the body of the `while` loop we always assign a not-`None` value to the `cur_node`. `cur_node = cur_node.left` when `cur_node.left` is not `None` and `cur_node = cur_node.right` when `cur_node.right` is not `None`.

Thus we need to get out of the loop somehow. One of the possible fixes for this might be changing the condition of the `while` loop to `True` to better express our intention and to `break` (or `return`) from the loop as soon as we have found the place to insert the item:

```
cur_node = self.root
while True :
  if data < cur_node.data:
    if cur_node.left is None:
      cur_node.left = Node(data)
      return # break is also possible
   else:
      cur_node = cur_node.left
  elif data > cur_node.data:
    if cur_node.right is None:
      cur_node.right = Node(data)
      return # break is also possible
    else:
      cur_node = cur_node.right
```

I noticed also that in your test you write the code like the insert returns something, but in fact it doesn't, so `insert` should be called like this

```
binary.insert(5)
binary.insert(4)
binary.insert(7)

print(binary.root.data) # 5
print(binary.root.left.data) # 4
print(binary.root.right.data) # 7
```

If you want the `insert` to return something, you first need to define what it should return (for example inserted node) and then change the code appropriately.